# Command for finding open ports

Tags: networking, osx, tcp, udp, netstat

On my linux servers I have this alias set:

```
alias ns="sudo lsof -Pi|grep -v ESTABL|grep -v CLOSED|grep -v -e '->' | 
tr -s ' ' '\t' | awk '{print $3 "\t" $8 "\t" $5 "\t" $9 "\t" $1}'|
column -t|sort"
```

It gives me output like this:

```
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       User       Inode       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:143             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      root       10459       2330/imap-login 
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22223           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      root       9646        4095/sshd       
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:25              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      root       10762       4724/master     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:443             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      root       8576        362/apache2     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      root       8574        362/apache2     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:993             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      root       10460       2330/imap-login 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:2000          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      root       10461       4639/dovecot    
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      mysql      10967       3454/mysqld     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:783           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      root       9748        4371/spamd.pid
```

I want the same output for OSX, but `lsof` etc. are behaving differently. I think because it comes from BSD.

The problems i'm having:

- When I just type the alias "ns" nothing is outputted.
- When I type the whole command I get the following output

output:

```
USER            NODE    TYPE  NAME                        COMMAND
_locationd      UDP     IPv4  *:*                         locationd
_mdnsresponder  UDP     IPv4  *:5353                      mDNSRespo
_mdnsresponder  UDP     IPv4  *:54398                     mDNSRespo
_mdnsresponder  UDP     IPv6  *:5353                      mDNSRespo
_mdnsresponder  UDP     IPv6  *:54398                     mDNSRespo
_netbios        UDP     IPv4  *:137                       netbiosd
_netbios        UDP     IPv4  *:138                       netbiosd
```

I need:

- numeric ports and adresses
- the whole command and PID

Comment: I don't know howto do that on Mac OSX, but on Linux you could as well do `netstat -ntpl` for TCP or `netstat -nupl` for UDP

Comment: If you gave us an example of the `lsof` output on OSX we might be able to help you parse it. Did you try `netstat` as suggested by @mauro?

Comment: I added more info. I tried netstat, but i had troubles with it at well. I can't get the PID to be displayed, or the ports limited to address-family.